# Dynamic PackageName on android

Tags: android, package

I want to change my application package name at run time using some script or some other way. But I don't know whether it is feasible in android or not.

Can anybody help me out to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Android uses the package-name for example to check for updates on the market. What are you trying to accomplish anyways?

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically change the package name of your application. Your package name is basically the ID Android uses to identify your application. Also, it's pretty much "burned" into the APK, so the only way to change it would be to open up the APK and change it in there. However, that would probably require root.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Felix. I guess we can do so using some script but I am not sure how to achieve this. I have found some links which describes how to do so using build.xml but I am unable to do the same.